# Output SQL messages to a Log File

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an SQL script than runs a couple of DBBC commands. Is there a way to send the messages generated from executing these commands to a simple log file e.g "C:\log.txt"?

The messages I mean are the ones that appear in the messages box at the bottom of SQL Server 2005 Management Studio after a query has executed.

The reason for needing to do this is because I don't intend on having SQL Server Management Studio open so the messages can't be seen.

I am using SQL Server 2005 if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run scripts from the Command line using SQLCMD utility.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28SQL.90%29.aspx

You can run this through a batch file. It let's you log to a file.

You can automate such jobs using scheduling programs.

Answer (score 5):

In SSMS, click `Query->Results To...->Results To File`

Comment: The question isn't asking about results. Commands like `PRINT`, for example, don't output results and row counts from `INSERT` or `UPDATE` also aren't results unless you specify the `OUTPUT` of those commands.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wasn’t aware SQLCMD is a command line tool for running T-SQL statements and scripts.

so from the command line:

```
 sqlcmd -i script.sql -S <myserver> -E | tee "C:\log.txt"
```

- SQLCMD can be used to run a script or stored procedure on a local/remote SQL Server.
- SQLCMD is installed with SSMS and with the database engine. And on the machine with only client or application it can be installed from the [Command Line Utilities](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591).
- Supported Operating Systems - 
  Windows 10, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Please provide more details on your answer, e.g. how to install/use **sqlcmd**, explanation of parameters, what version of SQL Server you've been able to use it on, etc.